# Is it possible to ignore unknown scopes in IdentityServer4?

Tags: identityserver4

I have an app using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect package to authenticate against a server using IdentityServer4.

In the IdentityServer implementation, I have the standard set of scopes set up as `IdentityResource`.

```cs
return new List<IdentityResource>
{
  new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
  new IdentityResources.Profile(),
  new IdentityResources.Email(),
  new IdentityResources.Address(),
  new IdentityResources.Phone()
}
```

I want to add a new Identity Resource with a new scope to provide information. To test out backwards compatibility, I added the new scope in my app's `AddOpenIdConnect` callback:

```cs
.AddOpenIdConnect(options => {
  // snipping for brevity
  options.Scopes = new[] {
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "my-new-scope"  // <- Does not exist in Identity Server yet.
  };
})
```

According to the [OpenId Connect Core specification](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest) - scopes that unknown to the OpenId Provider *should* (emphasis theirs) be ignored. But when I try to authenticate, I get an `invalid_scope` error.

Is there a way to tell IdentityServer to ignore scopes it doesn't know about?

Comment: You could write your own implementation of `IScopeValidator`, inheriting from the existing default `ScopeValidator` and change `AreScopesValidAsync` to not reject when the requested API scope does not exist.

[Here's a reference point in the default `ScopeValidator`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/src/IdentityServer4/src/Validation/Default/ScopeValidator.cs#L175). Though based on the spec this could be something that one might expect to change in the default `ScopeValidator`.

Comment: current behavior compared to the spec looks like a real bug, so you can report it to github and see what happens, most likely the owners will thank you for fixing that : )